# SCEP Client for Embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, certificate, embedded-linux, pki, scep

I need to add SCEP functionality to an embedded Linux application, i.e. manual enrollment, auto enrollment, certificate renewal.

Could you advice a SCEP client available for embedded Linux which implements this functionality?

Thanks in advance.